# How to see logs on screen like console in azure webapp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed python code on azure webapp.

```
def main():
    logging.basicConfig(filename="logtesting",
                            filemode='a',
                            format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                            datefmt='%H:%M:%S',
                            level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.info("Main thread started...")
    print("Main thread started...")
```

I tried to see logs on `log stream` but unable to see anything like what we can see on console.

[image]

Is there any setting ? because `we do not have any option of App insight when we use python in azure webapp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-Change you code to log to the console.

-In App Service, click on the App Service Logs menu and enable Application Logging.

-You can see the logs streaming in the Portal by clicking on the Log
Stream menu or in a terminal using:

```
az webapp log tail --name <app-name> --resource-group <resourceGroup>
```